# socket io getting peer client certificate always returns empty object

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ssl-certificate

I need to check every peer client certificate through sockets, so I am using socket.io with NodeJS and here's what I did in the server to fetch the certificate:

**Server Side**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  let cert = socket.client.request.client.getPeerCertificate();
});
```

**Client Side**

```
  const io = require('socket.io-client'),
  ioClient = io.connect(
    'https://myawesomesockets.com',
    {
      secure: true
    }
  );
```

So the cert object is empty whenever I am trying to connect in the client. Is there something I am missing ? Thanks in advance !